# Overwriting and Image Open and Currently Binded to In WPF Program

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, filestream

I am binding to 5 different images in my program and wish to leave the capability of the user to replace or update the photos under the same name. So when updating these pictures, the binding will be notified and change while the program is running.

The program is a Digital VMB (visual management board) at my workplace, so it needs to remain running and have these photos be updated on the server without a hitch. Currently I am binding to a property in my C# which is a string containing the image location.

In c#:

```
public string OpenFilePathProp { get; set; }
```

In XAML:

```
<Image x:Name="OpenWOImage" Source="{Binding OpenFilePathProp}" Stretch="Fill" Margin="25,0,25,0"/>
```

When the user goes to copy and replace the image with the newer one, they can't as it's "currently open in another process". Which I suppose is the data binding in my WPF.

Can this be overcome by opening the images into a filestream and then binding to the stream? If so, I'm completely unsure on how to bind to a filestream; I'm quite new to WPF AND C#.

Thanks for the help. I HAVE tried to look for a solution to this, but I think I'm just getting confused and I don't think it will resolve my problem since it seems the binding is what's "keeping the image open" and I'm not sure how to bind to an Image object AND close that object to allow for overwriting

EDIT: Thought I should mention that I've managed to copy the images in question to the AppData folder for my VMB program,

like,

```
string AppData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\";

System.IO.File.Copy(Properties.Settings.Default.OpenWOFilePath, System.IO.Path.Combine(AppData, "ROAMaintenanceVMB\\OpenWOFilePath_Copy.jpeg"), true);
```

this way I can "check" every so often to see that someone has overwritten the photos on the server, and THEORETICALLY copy the "new" photos to the AppData folder, overwriting the previous versions. THIS is where the issue of the images already being open in another program arises.

Comment: Without a more specific question, a good [mcve] showing what you've tried, and a clear explanation of what specifically you're having trouble with, your question is too broad. That said, given what you've written so far, I would say it would make more sense to create a `WriteableBitmap` object for each binding, and then when you want to use a specific image file, open that independently, copy it into the `WriteableBitmap`, and then close the file.

Comment: Sorry if my questions is vague. There just seems to be 35 different ways to open images and I don't know anyway other than using a file path, to bind an Image control in WPF to an image. The Issue with just binding to a file path is you can't modify the file in that path because it's open by the program

Comment: Here is a specific question. How can I delete a file that is binded to my Image control while the program is running? For example, `<Image Name="AvgWOAge" Source="{Binding AvgAgeFilePathProp}" Stretch="None" />` Where the `AvgAgeFilePathProp` is a string property storing the file directory path of the image I wish to bind to AND overwrite regularly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Following **[Peter Duniho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3538012/peter-duniho)** suggestion about using `WriteableBitmap` worked in my instance.

```
string imagePath = "";
Uri imageUri = new Uri(imagePath);
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(imageUri);
ImageProperty = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapImage);
```

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageProperty}"/>
```

What's going on here is:

1. `BitmapImage` is created **from** the given `path`
2. `WriteableBitmap` is created **based on** the `BitmapImage` (a "deep copy"?)

The important thing here is the original image is **not locked**, as the binding is tied to **the copy** of the image of `WriteableBitmap` - **not to the image** itself, so the image can be deleted / replaced freely.